# Scan through the array a particular amount of times then cout the element

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11

I want to iterate though an array a particular number of times (`k`) and see where it stops for example, I have `1,2,3,4` the output value is `1` for `k = 5` because when ever it  reaches the end of the array it starts all over again and continues counting till it reaches `k = 5`; I hope this makes sense this is what I have so far:

```
int numbers[] = {1,2,3,4};
int count =0;
int K =5;

while (count !=k)
{
 //dont know what to do here
}
```

Please explain the logic as well I am unable to get this.

Comment: Totally unclear.

Comment: Cannot understand what you want to achieve. Please describe why the output for `1,2,4` shall be `1`. What are you "scanning" for? If it is an assignment, please post the original text of it.

Comment: @RichardCrittenm  okay i kinda edited my question please have a look
its really hard for me to explain :(
and its not an assignment questions 
its actually a question from here 
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/caesar-cipher-1

Comment: Put some code in the loop and maybe we can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your array is of size 4 which you know, if you want to know in which element you will be when you loop k-times through the array do:

`int c = numbers[k % 4];`

In your case `above c = 1;` you will not need to loop.

Answer (score 2):

Why iterate through the array at all? Just mod `K` by the size of the array `numbers`.

```
int numbers[] = {1,2,3,4};
int K = 5;

int arraySize = sizeof(numbers) / sizeof(numbers[0]);
int count = K % arraySize;
return numbers[count];
```